How to incorporate a 3rd party signature transaction using the Cardano CLI tools?
I'm trying to use the HEX encoded signature I've received from Fireblocks API when using their Raw Signing functionality, however I'm not sure how to use the encoded content when it comes to signing the transaction using the Cardano CLI tools. I've tried creating a witness using the binary data, however I've got an invalid format message which probably means that Cardano expects the signing file to be in a similar format (or maybe the same one) as the payment.skey used to normally sign transactions when there's no 3rd party wallet/API involved.
Given that Fireblocks probably isn't the only provider of such services, I'm guessing this feature is something more people encountered, and had to figure out depending on the signature provided by a 3rd party. Any information will be greatly appreciated! :)
